# Automate a subscription in SSRS weekly using Windows File Share

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I hope this one is simple.

I have a paginated report set up on the SSRS online service. There is a subscription feature that allows for the report to be sent to a destination automatically.

[image]

I have all of the settings set up, the schedule, Destination, and Delivery Options with a filepath.

[image]

The report can be run manually, and a file will appear at the desired file-path location. For some reason, despite setting a report specific schedule, the feature will not run automatically.

What requirement am I missing here?

Comment: Does SSRS Service Account has access / write permission to that file location?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will need to reach out to someone to confirm if this is the case or not. Are these permissions required to run the process manually? I figured since it is successful when run manually that it must have permissions.

Comment: Is there an error message in the Result column on your first pic.That would be a good place to start but it's whited-out. It should say that it could not save due to a permission issue.

Comment: Hello @HannoverFist, thank you for your response. That field describes the results from the last time the subscription was run. What makes this whole issue so confusing is that there are no error messages to work with. It runs fine when I manually start the process, but despite configuring the schedule it does not run automatically.